# pgAdmin Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have been facing an issue. My AWS RDS is set to public accessibility, and I have filled in all the information in pgAdmin 4. However, I keep encountering the error 'Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired.' Can someone help me?

this is my AWS RDS info

[image: I think the settings is okay]

and this is my pgAdmin 4

[image: General tab]

[image: connection tab]

okay, I think my info is correct, but I no idea it kept came out this error
[image: Error Message]

Help and thank you